# Copy and install exe on azure vm via powershell

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create an Azure VM and then copy an install file to the VM and then silently installing it. I have created a basic Azure Resource Group project, and can create and deploy the VM, but I can't figure out how to do everything from the powershell script.

Comment: Have you looked at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049729/windows-azure-powershell-copying-file-to-vm

Comment: Are you trying to install an MSI on the VM?  Or just execute/install a random EXE on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use a custom script extension to do what you want. In your ARM template, you can specify the url for a file and the command to run; Azure will handle getting the file onto your VM and running it based on your command. Here is an example from the Azure Quickstart Templates: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/windows-vm-custom-script

Hope this helps! :)