# How to copy file to VM using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure

Sounds very simple, but most of the answers given on the internet assume both computers are on the same network. What if they are not, e.g. I want to copy a file to Azure VM. There is a thread [Windows Azure Powershell Copying file to VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049729/windows-azure-powershell-copying-file-to-vm) , but its four years old and the answers require many steps.

Comment: No way to avoid it, if they're not on the same network, you have to emulate them being on the same network via opening up ports to allow scp or something. Otherwise you have to use some middleman (i.e. "the internet").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Rasmusgude, you can upload file to Azure File Share then mount Azure File Share to that VM.

Are you administrator of that VM?

If yes, you can enable WinRM and use WinRM to upload files to it.

About enable Azure VM WinRM, you should add port 5985 to Azure VM's NSG inbound rules and add port 5985 to windows firewall inbound rules.

Then use this script to create a session:

```
$username = 'user'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5985' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

About upload files to that VM, you can use this PowerShell command `Send-File -Path C:test.xml -Destination C: -Session $session`.

Here a [blog](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-send-files-over-winrm,2-886.html) about sending files over WinRM, please refer to it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Azure File Share (AFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share), and then:

1. [Mount the AFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) as a drive on the VM
2. Use the REST Api or a [library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#copy-files) to upload the files to the AFS